# Showing complete git hash -- not the compressed hash

Tags: git

How do we get a list with full hashes ?

```
git reflog
```

I could not find about it in the docs.

```
5826591 HEAD@{0}: commit : Forgot password
c8a98d1 HEAD@{1}: commit : cleaned
02338ed HEAD@{2}: commit : forward to login page
528bec8 HEAD@{3}: commit : password changed
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just execute:

```
> git reflog --no-abbrev
```

Comment: Did not know that one - much better

Comment: @maan81: it *is* in the docs, it's just cleverly hidden away in the `git log` documentation.  The secret is that `git reflog` calls `git log -g` (aka `git log --walk-reflogs`) to list the reflog entries, so the complete options lists are over in the `git log` documentation.

Answer (score 2):

*nb. I should mention this answer just list `commit`'s not all entries (like `rebase`, `pull` etc)*

[git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) can accept `format` options the same as [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

So you could use this…

```
git reflog show --format='%C(auto)%H %<|(17)%gd: commit : %s'
```

Which you get you output like this:

```
f2801fa5ea4a28b573ce14d6ca8502a9dd8dc7a1 HEAD@{39}: commit : Initial commit
7de68d559ccf7a3435af9ddaa432c81cb59a20fc HEAD@{40}: commit : Add Update packages playbook for simplicity
f63b2757f2b19188d89fe7bb0f76c56ebee3634f HEAD@{41}: commit : Preliminary structure
```